# How to add aria-label in html helper in VB.script

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add aria-label to @Html.TextBoxFor, something like,

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Config.Notes, New With {.id = "Notes", .class = "notes",.aria-label="something"})
```

But it doesnt seems the correct syntax. Any idea the correct syntax ?